# How to check if ajax return exist?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'DBConnector.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
//check if exist
}
});
```

This is what i return:

```
echo json_encode(array("data" => $returnValue , "status" => "false"));
```

How to check if status **exist**(not to be false but really if it exist)?

Comment: alert(data); or alert('success');//check if exist

Comment: Can you please be more clear?

Comment: success: function(data){
alert(data.data);
} this alert the $returnValue value

Comment: I don't want it to alert but I want to use it in an if statement

Comment: Someone else explained it to me already so my question isn't necessary anymore. But thank you for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'DBConnector.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data.status !== undefined)
        {
            //YOUR CODE HERE
        }
    }
});
```

It will check if the `status` exists or not.